# In Java How to handle all the child class with Single function which accept Its Parent class

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, arraylist

I have a class name `Rocket` which have 2 methods name `launch and land`(which store the probability of crash at launch and land ) and 2 other `child class of Rocket U1 and U2` which overwrite `launch and land` respectively.So in Main i wrote 2 method Simulation U1 and Simulation U2 which accept object of U1 and U2 respectively and calculate if the mission will be successful or not(and also calculate other stuffs like cost etc but are exactly identical) . My both method Simulation U1 and Simulation U2 do exactly the same thing but only difference is that first one accept U1 object and second One accept U2 object. So is there any method through i write a method which accept Rocket object and and depending on the object passed can access the respective methods of that class.

```
void runSimulationU1(ArrayList<U1> rocketList) {
totalCost=0;
    U1 rocketU1;
    for (int i = 0; i < rocketList.size(); i++) {
        rocketU1 = rocketList.get(i);
        boolean x = true;
        while (x) {
            if ((rocketU1.launch() && (rocketU1.land()))) {
                totalCost += rocketU1.cost;
                x = false;
            } else {
                totalCost += rocketU1.cost;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Total cost:"+totalCost+" Million");
}
void runSimulationU2(ArrayList<U2> rocketList) {
totalCost=0;
    U2 rocketU2;
    for (int i = 0; i < rocketList.size(); i++) {
        rocketU2 = rocketList.get(i);
        boolean x = true;
        while (x) {
            if ((rocketU2.launch() && (rocketU2.land()))) {
                totalCost += rocketU2.cost;
                x = false;
            } else {
                totalCost += rocketU2.cost;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Total cost:"+totalCost+" Million");

}
```

As you can see this code is repeated so is there any way to make this code more perfect.

my rocket class

```
public abstract class Rocket implements SpaceShip {
    int cost=0;
    @Override
    public abstract boolean launch();

    @Override
    public  abstract boolean land() ;
    @Override
    public boolean canCarry(Item item,int totalCargo,int maxLimit) {
        if(totalCargo+item.weight<=maxLimit){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int carry(Item item,int currentWeight) {
        currentWeight = currentWeight+item.weight;
        return currentWeight;
    }
}
```

my U2 class

```
public class U2 extends Rocket {
 final int cost = 120;
 final int maxLimit =29_000;
 public int totalCargo=18_000;
 U2(int totalCargo){
     this.totalCargo=totalCargo;
 }
public boolean land(){
    double probability = (8/100)*(totalCargo/maxLimit);
    double randomValue =Math.random();
    return randomValue>=probability;
}
public boolean launch(){
    double probability = (4/100)*(totalCargo/maxLimit);
    double randomValue =Math.random();
    return randomValue>=probability;
}
```

}
my U1 class

```
public class U1 extends Rocket {
final int cost = 100;
final int maxLimit =18_000;
public  int totalCargo=10_000;
U1(int totalCargo){
    this.totalCargo=totalCargo;
}
public boolean land(){
    double probability = (1/100)*(totalCargo/maxLimit);
    double randomValue =Math.random();
    return randomValue>=probability;
}
public boolean launch(){
    double probability = (5/100)*(totalCargo/maxLimit);
    double randomValue =Math.random();
    return randomValue>=probability;
}
```

}
my spaceShip interface

```
 interface SpaceShip {
boolean launch();
boolean land();
boolean canCarry(Item item,int totalCargo,int maxLimit);
int carry(Item item ,int currentWeight);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: use List, not ArrayList ... except in that one place where you do `new ArrayList`. Always prefer to use the interface type, not some specific implementation type (as parameter, or field or variable type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can weaken the type of `rocketList` to `Iterable<? extends >`. It will let `runSimulation` accept objects of any type, which is a subtype of `Iterable<? extends Rocket>` (e.g. `ArrayList<U1>`, `ArrayList<U2>`, `HashSet<Rocket>`, `Collection<U1>`, `Collection<? extends U2>`).

```
void runSimulation(Iterable<? extends Rocket> rockets) {
    int totalCost = 0;
    for (Rocket rocket : rockets)
        do {
            totalCost += rocket.getCost();
        } while (!(rocket.launch() && rocket.land()));
    System.out.println("Total cost:" + totalCost + " Million");
}
```

Comment: this method is running but there is an issue instead of rocket.getCost() being the cost of the rocket U1 or U2 it is accessing cost of base class Rocket which is zero

Comment: thank you first i was trying to access using cost directly then i use getCost method for getting the cost so now it works perfectly fine.